# use groupby to upsample multiple dataframe columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Is there a way to **groupby** first by group,
and then to upsample education AND income(so that rows are copied in a way that
the new **dataframe** is has equal occurrences / is balanced across education and income)?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1,2,2,1,2,2],
                   'X1':[10,11,30,10,30,8],
                   'X2':[0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.8,0.1], 
                   'education':[2,0,2,2,0,2], 
                   'income':[3,2,6,1,2,1]})
```

the output would have equal counts of classes (balanced):

```
   group  X1   X2  education  income  
       1  10  0.2          0       3   
       1  10  0.2          0       3   
       1  10  0.2          0       1   
       1  10  0.2          0       1   
       2  11  0.3          2       2   
       2   8  0.1          2       2   
       2  30  0.2          2       6   
       2  30  0.8          2       6
```

Comment: Can you provide an example output?

Comment: @mozway sure, I edited my example. I hope I described it more clearly. The outcome is "upsample minorities to the largest class, so that "group" has equal class occurences of "education" and "income"

Comment: It is not really clear. Do you just want to have an equal number of values, but where are those values doesn't matter? How come education for group 1 are only zeros where they were only ones before?

Comment: okay, let me try it once again: the two groups (group 1 and group 2) should have balanced education and income values. That means in case of my little example that I need to copy data points (for example, "income" only had one "3" occurence, but to get equal distribution of all categories, the data point has been copied or "upsamped"). The idea is to even out the differences between classes. Regarding your question, I changed  the "education" variable in the original posting to make it more simple. Sorry if that led to confusion